# Expose views as JSON

Tags: views, 6

I'd like to expose data/views coming from 6.19 as json.

What I tried so far are the JsonRPC/REST service modules, but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds that you need [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module:

> Views Datasource is a set of plugins for Drupal Views for rendering content in a number of shareable, reusable formats based on XML, JSON and XHTML.